# Localisation in Asp.net Core 2.0 not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have added localisation like below. However, its not displaying the relevant values.

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  // Add swagger here using extension methods.
  services.AddSwaggerService();

  // Add language support here.
  // Default language is English. Supported
  // languages are English and French.
  services.AddLanguageSupport();

  // Add controller
  services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
                    .AddViewLocalization()
                    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(options =>
                    {
                      options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
                      {
                        var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(typeof(SharedResource).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName);
                        return factory.Create("SharedResource", assemblyName.Name);
                      };
                      })
                    .AddControllersAsServices();
}
```

The extension method for language support:

```
public static void AddLanguageSupport(this IServiceCollection services)
{
  // Add list of supported cultures
  // here. Two languages are English
  // and french.
  services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

  services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(
      options =>
      {
        var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
              {
                        new CultureInfo("en"),
                        new CultureInfo("fr"),
              };

        options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "en", uiCulture: "en");
        options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
        options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
      });
}
```

The middleware:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
  var locOptions = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
  app.UseRequestLocalization(locOptions.Value);
}
```

[image]

In Resources folder, I have the following:

SharedResource class:

```
public class SharedResource
{
}
```

LocService class:

```
public class LocService
{
private readonly IStringLocalizer _localizer;

/// <summary>
/// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="LocService"/> class.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="factory">factory.</param>
public LocService(IStringLocalizerFactory factory)
{
  var type = typeof(SharedResource);
  var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(type.GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName);
  _localizer = factory.Create("SharedResource", assemblyName.Name);
}

/// <summary>
/// returns localised string for a key.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="key">key.</param>
/// <returns>localised string.</returns>
public LocalizedString GetLocalizedHtmlString(string key)
{
  return _localizer[key];
}
}
```

The Controller:

```
public class AuthController : ControllerBase
{
private readonly IStringLocalizer<SharedResource> _localizer;

public AuthController(IStringLocalizer<SharedResource> localizer)
{
  _localizer = localizer;
}

public async Task<ActionResult> Post([FromBody] LoginModel login)
{     
    if (await _userService.IsUserAuthenticatedAsync(login.UserName, login.Password))
    {
      responseToken = await _userService.GetResponseToken(login.UserName);

      statusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;

      tokenResponseMessage = new ResponseMessage(true, responseToken, new Message(statusCode));

      // generate access token
      response = Ok(tokenResponseMessage);
    }
    else
    {
      statusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
      tokenResponseMessage = new ResponseMessage(false, null, new Message(statusCode, 
      _localizer["Login_InCorrectUserNamePassword"]));

      response = Unauthorized(tokenResponseMessage);
    }
  }

  return response;
}
```

_localizer["Login_InCorrectUserNamePassword"])) returns Login_InCorrectUserNamePassword in Swagger.

Comment: If, you're using the default indexer, like you're doing in your code sample, then as far as I know, the
IStringLocalizer looks for a localized version of the string matching the current culture by using the .NET framework’s ResourceManager. That means, instead of the key `Login_InCorrectUserNamePassword` you need to actually use the string that Login_InCorrectUserNamePassword outputs in the default culture. `Invalid login attempt.` for example. And if you want to use the key instead, use the IStringLocalizer's GetString() method and pass in the key `Login_InCorrectUserNamePassword`.

Answer (score 0):

You could always go into the folder `YourProject\obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.1` to see your resource file (for example, `MyProjectName.Resources.SharedResource.en.resource`).

Check the result of `_localizer["Login_InCorrectUserNamePassword"]` to find its value of `SearchedLocation`.It should match the file name of resource file.

In my case,the `SharedResource.cs` have a namespace like `namespace MyProjectName.Resources` instead of `namespace MyProjectName` which leads to wrong `SearchedLocation` ——`MyProjectName.Resources.Resources.SharedResource` since I have used

```
services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
```

Change its namespace to below and it works:

```
namespace MyProjectName
{
    public class SharedResource
    {
    }
}
```